# "Classes" unit implementation

Tags: delphi, freepascal

Maybe I am blind, but I can't find in the Free Pascal source file implementations of Classes and some other units like System. Mostly, but not only, I am interested in `TObject`, `TPersistent` and `TControl` code code. I searched both in Lazarus and FP sites on SourceForge. My problem is that the file list is quite large. Google refused to search because of `robots.txt`.

There is a [lclclasses.pas](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tags/lazarus_0_9_30_4RC3/lcl/lclclasses.pp?view=markup&revision=35874&root=lazarus) unit, but it is not what I'm looking for - in the `uses` block it is referring to Classes, but there is no file (I mean I couldn't find it) like "classes.pas".

[Here](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/release_0_9_30_2_rc1/lcl/include/control.inc?view=markup&revision=31606&root=lazarus) I found the `TControl` implementation, but that's too far in the hierarchy.

On [this page](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tpersistent.html) there is an information that the `TPersistent` is defined in "classesh.inc" and I downloaded sources and it really is in rtl\objpas\classes\classesh.inc, however, it seems that this file is only `interface` part of the unit.

I tagged this question as "delphi" too, because in fact if there is some open source code for Delphi, I could also accept. If the implementation of this base classes `TObject` and `TPersistent` is some kind of built-in feature (the `System` unit is, I think), I can also take a look at C (or any other language) sources.

Could anybody help me to find implementation of Classes units and the objects defined there?

Comment: They can be founf in .inc files

Comment: I get it. The files are divided rather by classes not the units. Thank you @DavidHeffernan

Comment: I suggest you both: @DavidHeffernan convert that comment in a answer and Voitcus accept it. Is not that obvious for those starting with Lazarus.

Comment: Yes @DavidHeffernan, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because FPC supports so many different platforms, the structure of the RTL code is somewhat complex.

But the platform independent part of the RTL code, which is what you are interested in can be found under the `source\rtl\objpas` directory.

- The code for `Classes` is in include files in `source\rtl\objpas\classes`. The relevant files are `classesh.inc` and `classes.inc`. The former contains the code for the interface section, the latter code for the implementation section.
- The `System` unit is highly platform specific. Look for your platform under `source\rtl`.
- For `SysUtils` look under `source\rtl\objpas\sysutils`.

Comment: Note that I am not even remotely an expert on FPC. I've written this answer mainly because I have been asked to. If I've got anything wrong I would appreciate corrections.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert to answer this particular question :) Thanks again.